# sqlcmd: Native Client 11.0 does not support connections to SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to execute an SQL script using the sqlcmd utility, but it uses the SQL Server Native Client 11.0 and returns the error in the title. In Management Studio, I can connect to the database engine using the Client version 10.0. Is there any way to use version 10.0 using sqlcmd?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you should have a version 10.0 copy of `sqlcmd` in the following path:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.exe

(If you don't, then download a version of 2008 Express with Tools and install just the client tools.)

Just call that directly instead of the default one with no path (which will usually default to the most recent version).